# I was wondering about how I might collect user’s scores for a math quiz I made

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to collect user’s scores from my GitHub page (theratcoder.github.io). I have used the following JS code (embedded in my HTML document) to create my quiz.

var score = 0;

```
var times33 = window.prompt("3 x 3");
switch(times33) {
  case "9":
    document.write("correct, ");
    score++;
    break;
  default:
    document.write("incorrect, ");
    break;
}

var subtract5221 = window.prompt("52 - 21");
switch(subtract5221) {
  case "31":
    document.write("correct, ");
    score++;
    break;
  default:
    document.write("incorrect, ");
    break;
}

var add56 = window.prompt("5 + 6");
switch(add56) {
  case "11":
    document.write("correct, ");
    score++;
    break;
  default:
    document.write("incorrect, ");
    break;
}

var divide183 = window.prompt("18 / 3");
switch(divide183) {
  case "6":
    document.write("correct - ");
    score++;
    break;
  default:
    document.write("incorrect - ");
    break;
}
var finishing_text;
switch(score) {
  case 4:
    finishing_text = "Great job!";
    break;
  case 3:
    finishing_text = "Well done.";
    break;
  case 2:
    finishing_text = "Better luck next time!";
    break;
  case 1:
    finishing_text = "You need to work on your math!";
    break;
  default:
    finishing_text = "You really need to work on your math!";
    break;
}
var submit = window.confirm("Do you want to submit this quiz?");
var percent = score / 4 * 100;
if (submit) {
  document.write("Your final score is " + score + " out of 4 (" + percent + "%). ");
  document.write(finishing_text);
}
else {
 location.reload(); 
}
```

I want to collect the values of the variable “score” so that I can get an idea of how people generally do on my quiz.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you get 0?

Comment: No, there is no problem, I just want an (relatively) easy way to collect data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do something like that, you'll need two things, a way to get the data to some form of storage, and the storage itself.

Unless some things have changed, github.io sites are static content only, so there's no server running in the background that you can access and communicate with your storage from, just your static content being served by the github.io service and running in the user's browser.

So the basic answer is you can't. But that's not true and there's always a hack if you're willing to do something gnarly. (I assume this is just for fun?)

If that's the case, you could run a server on your computer at home or something. Then when the user answers a question you add a call to the server on your computer at home and it takes that data and saves it and aggregates it however you want.

But end of the day if you want to store things about your users, you're probably going to want to have a dynamic website.

Although, maybe take a look at this if you're determined: https://medium.com/pan-labs/dynamic-web-apps-on-github-pages-for-free-ffac2b776d45 -- it's something like the "send data to your own computer" step, but using the free tier of firebase instead.